# Weird error in using Ant

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

This is my build.xml using ant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="compile" default="css.concatenate" basedir=".">
<property name="charset" value="utf-8"/>

<!-- compile LESS -->

<target name="css.concatenate">
    <concat destfile="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/cons/cons.less">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/less">
            <include name="*.less"/>
        </fileset>
    </concat>
    <echo>cons is done!</echo>
</target>

<target name="lessc" depends="css.concatenate">
    <echo>now in compression</echo>
    <java classname="CpLess" fork="true">
        <arg value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/cons"/><!-- input folder that contains less file -->
        <arg value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css"/><!-- output folder -->
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/js.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/lesscss-engine.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/yuicompressor.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/zkjszips.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/zkless.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/zul.jar"/> <!-- only needed if using _zkmixins.less -->
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="rename" depends="lessc">
    <echo>renaming...</echo>
    <rename src="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css/cons.css.dsp" dest="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css/core.css"/>
    <delete file="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css/cons.css.dsp.src"/>
    <echo>rename done</echo>
</target>


<target name="trasition" >
            <echo> in trasition </echo>

</target>



</project>
```

When I run this, it comes into the error like this:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\lessCompiler\build.xml
css.concatenate:
 [echo] cons is done!
lessc:
 [echo] now in compression
 [java] Compiling...      C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\lessCompiler\src\main\webapp\cons\cons.less
css.concatenate:
 [echo] cons is done!
css.concatenate:
 [echo] cons is done!
lessc:
 [echo] now in compression
 [java] Compiling...    C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\lessCompiler\src\main\webapp\cons\cons.less
 rename:
 [echo] renaming...
 [rename] DEPRECATED - The rename task is deprecated.  Use move instead.
 [delete] Deleting:  C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\lessCompiler\src\main\webapp\css\cons.css.dsp.src
 [echo] rename done
 trasition:
 [echo]  in trasition 

BUILD FAILED
Target "precompile-templates" does not exist in the project "compile". 

Total time: 4 seconds
```

As you can see, it says "precompile-templates" target is not exist. However, I didn't call this task at all. I just delete it from my build.xml and there are no other targets related to it. How does the error come? PS: I use eclipse's run as ANT to run this build.xml.

Comment: I know very little about ANT but I think you weren't supposed to delete it, and now it's complaining that it can't find it.

Comment: But I do not need the "precompile-templates" anymore, it is no use. This is really weird. Is that mean that if you create an target in ant, then you can never delete it, or it will come to an error?

Comment: Was precompile templates something you created?

Comment: Are you running this from Eclipse as an 'External Tool'?

Comment: I create the "precompile-templates" target and delete it. And I think I do running this from Eclipse as an 'External Tool'. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out the problem. I still use the old configuration to run the build.xml. The solution is like this:

1. right click on the build.xml
2. click 'run as...' then click the external configuration tool
3. delete the selected launch configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the target you want to run after you deleted the unnecessary targets from the file? It looks to me like the run configuration is still using the old target. Use

Comment: No, you can see that all the target which will run have nothing to do with the "precompile-templates"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you created a target "precompile-templates", you subsequently deleted it ... and Eclipse is "remembering" the now-obsolete target.

SUGGESTION:
1) "File > Save all", 2) "Project > Clean project" 3) "Run As, Ant build"

See if that works!

Answer (score -1):

Para aquel que le interese
buil.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="less.compile" default="css.concatenate" basedir=".">
<!-- compile LESS -->
<target name="css.concatenate">
    <concat destfile="${basedir}/WebContent/cons/index.less">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/WebContent/less/import">
            <include name="*.less"/>
        </fileset>
    </concat>
    <echo>cons is done!</echo>
</target>

 <target name="css.lessc">
        <java classname="CpLess" fork="true">
            <arg value="${basedir}/WebContent/cons"/><!-- output folder -->
            <arg value="${basedir}/WebContent/less"/><!-- output folder -->
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-     logging.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/lesscss-engine-1.3.3.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zkjszips.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zkless.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zul.jar"/><!-- only needed if using _zkmixins.less -->
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

<target name="lessc">
    <java classname="CpLess" fork="true">
        <arg value="C:/WKSLuna000/PruebasZul/WebContent/lesssrc"/><!-- output folder -->
        <arg value="C:/WKSLuna000/PruebasZul/WebContent/lessbuild"/><!-- output folder -->
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/lesscss-engine-1.3.3.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zkjszips.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zkless.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/zul.jar"/><!-- only needed if using _zkmixins.less -->
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
</project>


En la carpeta cons/
                  /zk/
                      _header.less
                      _zkminis.less
                      _skvariables.less
En la carpeta less/
                  /import/
                         0index.less
                         button.less
                         ....
                         /zk/
                             _header.less
                            _zkminis.less
                            _skvariables.less

Archivo 0index.less:
@import "../bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import "../bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
@import "zk/_header.less";
```

Comment: please write your answer in english